# How to draw numbers-triangle in C++ console app?

Tags: c++, drawing

How to draw numbers-triangle in C++ console app like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpqIf.png ?

Thank you!

Comment: Start with a simpler exercise: print the sequence of numbers from 1 to n and from n to 1. You should involve a loop for that.

Answer (score 1):

Following program is one of the method to do so.

```
int main()
{
    const int MAXIMUM_DIMENSION = 8;
    int padding = 0;
    for (int count = MAXIMUM_DIMENSION; count > 0; count--)
    {
        // Calculate padding (space needed from start)
        padding = MAXIMUM_DIMENSION - count;
        for (int paddingIndex = 0; paddingIndex < padding; paddingIndex++)
        {
            // For padding
            std::cout << "\t";
        }


        for (int printValue = 1; printValue < count * 2; printValue++)
        {
            if( printValue > count)
            {
                // Decreasing pattern
                std::cout << count - (printValue - count);
            }
            else
            {
                // Increasing pattern
                std::cout << printValue;
            }

            std::cout << "\t";
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Better you should study loops in C++.